# What's the email address to get in touch with SDL for product pricing information

Tags: 2013

Anyone could help me here to find the email address to get in touch with SDL for product pricing information ?

Comment: You can also contact me. Use first letter of first name + last name at sdl.com and I'll redirect you to the right person.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your best option is to use the contact form on the website: http://www.sdl.com/contact/

You would have to choose one of the five areas of interest, to see which products fall under these CXC solution categories, check out http://www.sdl.com/cxc/all-products.html